# Isn't PTR redundant in this instruction : CALL DWORD PTR [XXXXXXXX]

Tags: assembly, masm

Isn't PTR redundant in this instruction  `CALL DWORD PTR [XXXXXXXX]`. If the instruction was `CALL DWORD [XXXXXXXX]` This also says, Call the DWORD length value located at the address XXXXXXXX.

Why PTR then?

Answer (score 0):

If i remember right, the "PTR" operator is there because in MASM, there are times when you can have an expression that looks like a regular value but is actually a pointer.

If both statements work for you, all i can say is, assemble them both and make sure they both generate the same bytes.  They ought to be the same thing, considering the "xxxxxxxx" in `[xxxxxxxx]` is by definition a pointer, but it's been a while since i last coded in MASM. (NASM, which i tend to favor, is far less confusing about such things.)

Answer (score 0):

In masm parlance, DWORD PTR is a pointer override, IOW what you would usually call a cast. It basically means, "consider address XXXXXXXX as a DWORD pointer".

masm actually types its data items. So if XXXXXXXX has previously been defined as

```
XXXXXXXX DWORD SomeAddress   ; Presumably a function entry point.
```

then

```
 CALL XXXXXXXX
```

is enough and will generate the same code as

```
  CALL DWORD PTR XXXXXXXX
```

OTOH, if for some reason, XXXXXXXX were instead defined as

```
XXXXXXXX  WORD ?
          WORD ?
```

then the only way to get MASM to assemble a call to XXXXXXXX without generating a mams error would be

```
  CALL DWORD PTR XXXXXXXX
```

The square brackets [ ] don't bring anything to the plate in this case, BTW. For some other assemblers, they indicates indirection. In the examples above, masm doesn't require them. In other contexts (base + index expressions), they are used to bracket the index registers and/or values.

Oh, and btw:

```
  CALL DWORD [XXXXXXXX]
```

is today an unusual masm syntax (per masm 6 documentation books and their examples), and probably a compatibility allowance corresponding to some older masm syntax.